# ETL associated with HADOOP database Hbase?

Tags: hadoop, etl, hbase

HI  can anybody tell me which are the ETL Tools which can be used with Hbase which is the database of hadoop?
I mean to say like how the data in oracle database is used to pull data and work with in tools like Informatica and SSIS,is there any ETL tool that can be used for Hbase?
Kindly help me.

Comment: A simple and flexible tool: [hbase etl](https://github.com/khangich/hbase-etl)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Pentaho Data Integration for Hadoop](http://www.pentaho.com/products/hadoop/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out Cascading.HBase http://www.cascading.org/modules.html